# notistack items not rendered into provided domRoot container

Tags: reactjs, typescript, tsx, aria-live, notistack

My goal is it to display the notisstack snackbar items inside a div-container which is readable by screenreaders. Therefore I wanted to use the [domRoot](https://notistack.com/api-reference) property of the SnackbarProvider.

I'am using notistack [`3.0.7`](https://notistack.com/api-reference)

My Problem is now, that the div-container element is rendered but not used as the root for my snackbaritem. I have only defined a single SnackbarProvider.

[image: dom screenshot]

index.tsx

```
const SnackbarProviderWrapper = () => {

    const alertContainer = React.createElement('div', {
        "aria-live": "assertive",
        className: "alert-container"
    }) as unknown as HTMLElement

    return (
        <SnackbarProvider anchorOrigin={{vertical: "bottom", horizontal: "center"}}
                          domRoot={alertContainer}
                      >
            <App/>
            {alertContainer}
        </SnackbarProvider>
    )
}


ReactDOM.render(
    <React.StrictMode>
                <SnackbarProviderWrapper/>
    </React.StrictMode>,
    document.getElementById('root')
);
```

Answer (score 1):

Ok I found a workaround solution. It is no exceptional "dirty" but not clean either.

First I moved the `SnackbarProvider` to a component, in my case the App component to have access to hooks.
Than I used a component for my container instead of `React.createElement(...)`. This component forwards its div-Element via forwardRef. Finaly we manage the Element via a `useState()` hook.

```
/**
 * This is the Element that will be used as a container for all notistack snackbar items
 */
const AlertContainer = React.forwardRef<HTMLDivElement>((props, ref) => (
    <div ref={ref} className="alert-container" aria-live={"assertive"}>
        {props.children}
    </div>
));

function App() {
    const [alertContainer, setAlertContainer] = useState<HTMLDivElement | null>(null)

    return (
        <>
            <AlertContainer ref={setAlertContainer}/>
            {alertContainer ?
                <SnackbarProvider anchorOrigin={{vertical: "bottom", horizontal: "center"}}
                                  domRoot={alertContainer}>
                    <main/>
                </SnackbarProvider>
                : null /* we must have this conditon to render the DOM once so our AlertContainer is present*/}
        </>
    );
}
```

You might ask why not use a `useRef()` hook? That is because the Tree must render at least once before using the container component.
For this reason we have also added the condition that returns `null` on the first render. If we don't have this our AlertContainer componente is not yet present in the DOM and domRoot will be `null`.

It is strange that notistack expects an already initialized HTMLElement for the property `domRoot`. This prohibits us from using a regular ref here.
This is especially strange since there is no need to use an existing DOM element. The element must be present when an Alert/SnackbarItem must be displayed, not before.